# Unable to switch to debug build variant in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've switched to release build variant and configured signingConfigs. Now when I try to check the debug build variant from the drop down menu it switches immediately back to the release build variant. So I'm not able to run my app in debug mode any more.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            ...
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kost.foo"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
        }
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
               ...
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni']
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path 'src/main/jni/CMakeLists.txt'
        }
    }
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://github.com/linchaolong/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo' }
    mavenCentral()

}
```

I've tried to revert all changes in build.gradle as it was before configuring, but with no luck.

Any ideas how to fix the issue?

Comment: Did you try to sync project manually with the gradle files?

Comment: @ridoy Yes, tried. Didn't help

Comment: I am also facing same issue

Comment: I cannot say I've solved it as I still don't know what caused the problem. But the fastest work around I found was to push the project to git (bitbucket in my case) and check it out from version control in a new project.

Comment: I followed your work around and it did helped !!! Thanks  @AlexKost

Comment: Synching solved my problem.

Comment: Why do you have **debuggable true** in your release type?

Comment: @Igor Ganapolsky I was just playing around with different flags in order to get some more information and insight on what was going on. I removed it afterwords.

Comment: @AlexKost, No accepted answer for this question?

Comment: @shizhen As I stated in the comment above I was bale to work around the problem. After that I never run again into the same problem, so I was unable to check any other solution. Some of them might provide a better one, though. The most upvoted answer seems to be outdated.

Answer (score 32):

I had a similar problem where most of the Build menu items were greyed out.
[image: greyed out]

'Sync project with Gradle files' didn't fix.

I noticed a 'Build Variants' toggle button on the bottom left of Android Studio (v 3.1.2) and with this was finally able to choose the variant I needed.

[image: Choose variant from here]

Maybe this will work for you too.

Answer (score 14):

Maybe you have got your solution to this, just in case, i provide my solution here.

---

**For Android Studio 2.x**

It may because that you compile your dependent project using:

```
compile project('module_a')
```

Above setting will force your project to compile the release version of your modules. Just change it to below:

```
releaseCompile project(path: ':module_a', configuration: 'release')
debugCompile project(path: ':module_a', configuration: 'debug')
```

---

**For Android Studio 3.x**

You don't need to explicitly specify the build variant for a "module project". Just using

```
implementation project(':library')
```

will **automatically** help select the correct build variant.

Here is a detailed explanation: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/?utm_source=android-studio#variant_aware

---

**For Android Studio 3.x Upgraded from 2.x**

Delete the `.idea` folder under your project root directory and restart your Android Studio.

Below is the GUI screenshot:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: this is only for older gradle versions: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33718663/gradle-error-configuration-declares-dependency-which-is-not-declared), refer to post by @rockefelox  for newer versions

Comment: True. Since Android Studio 3.0, all the xxxCompile closures change to xxxImplementation.

Comment: For Android Studio 3.1.2, you don't need to explicitly specify the build variant for a "module project". Just using implementation project(':library') will automatically help select the correct build variant. Here is a detailed explanation https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration?utm_source=android-studio#variant_aware .

Answer (score 14):

Just need to cut ".idea" Folder and paste it outside Project root folder( For Back up if you need).These files will be auto regenerated. On Opening the project it"ll ask add module (app) to your project. You can ignore the same.

It set set default build variant to be "debug".
You can see build variant tab on left corner or hover on "Monitor" Symbol on left bottom to get build variant option.

Comment: This is the solution what worked for me in Android Studio 3.1.2

Comment: Good to know that It helped you. :)

Comment: worked for me also. Just deleted .idea folder and re-created workspace by reading build.gradle

Comment: i needed to remove and re-import the project as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45950059/5443056

Comment: For some reason deleting `.idea` folder and `invalidate cache and restart` did not work. and deleting it and just restarting worked.

Answer (score 11):

I just had the same issue. Solved it by closing Android Studio, removing the generated files and folders: `.gradle`, `.idea`, `app/.externalNativeBuild`, `app/build`, `build`, `app/app.iml`, `ProjectName.iml`, `local.properties`, then relaunching Android Studio and allowing it regenerate all these files from scratch.

Comment: Only had to delete `rm -rf ./.gradle ./app/.gradle .idea/caches/`

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem, solved creating a new temporary Build Type, Build > Edit Build Types, select Build Types and add a new one. Sync, then you can select the new build type, and then revert back to original Debug build type.

Comment: Was the only solution that worked for me Android Studio 3.4.2

Comment: On Android Studio, these types of solutions are always the best.

Answer (score 2):

Open your module setting. (Click F4)

Go to build types and create a new Build by clicking on plus(+) sign.

Name it anything, like "demo".

Duplicate all the data of debug build.

Now when you open Build Variant you will be able to switch to Debug as well as Demo.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue. My module level build.gradle reflected configurations specified for "debug" AND "release" accordingly. I was able to successfully run my app on emulator and device (LG) prior To Building and Signing My Release Version Of My App. After Building and Signing The Release Version and attempting to Run The Signed APK on My Phone and Device, i received an Error `PM Session 'mobile': Error Launching activity....Error while Launching activity`..So I started retracing my steps and realized that before deploying the signed release variant, i opened up the **run/debug Configurations Dialog**[image]

and mistakenly selected the the Value **APK from app bundle** value From The **Deploy** attribute, under the *Installation* category
[image]

***I Signed My APK In its ENTIRETY and NOT Via Bundle***, so the option selected was attempting to Deploy an invalid App Bundle That Was Never Generated To Begin With, even if it was for the correct **Build Variant**.

Answer (score 1):

For me I was unable to switch to our 'devDebug' variant but I could switch to another variant like 'devRelease' and then 'devDebug'. So try switching to another variant first.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was an issue with the gradle version. Make sure your plugin version and the required gradle version fit together, as defined here.

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

You can find out which gradle versions you are using under:

File -> Project Structure... -> Project

Comment: I got solution after update the gradle version and its plugin version

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above to no effect.  Eventually stumbled across File > Invalidate Caches/Restart... for other reasons and found it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have this question too. My solution is checkout to the branch which i had changed the build variants. And at that branch, I can change from release back to debug. Then just checkout to current branch and everything is OK. It seems to be a Android Studio bug.

Answer (score 0):

> English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

I also meet this situation. i do this to solv .
Solv:
1. delete `each module's` **impl** suffix type file and **build** folder;
2. then click this button to sync project with gradle build file.     [button position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alch0.jpg)

finally. and then this problem  will be fix.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issued by:

1. Add a new build type named debug1 via edit build.gradle;Enable debug function of this build type;
2. Sync and select the new build type debug1;

Comment: But I don't know why I can't to switch to the original debug mode.Anyway,steps above fixed the issue that can't  debug.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to occur when opening the project in a symlinked location on linux. Opening the project directly fixed this issue for me.

relevant link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156857164

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include any important content from the link that's relevant to the question in the answer itself. Answers that consist primarily of a link to somewhere else can become invalid if the link stops working for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

in main root of app in build.gradle

replace it from:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
}
```

to my Android Studio v3.0.1 in my case:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

March 26, 2021:
Would not switch from Release to Debug,
File | Invalidate Caches fixed it for me

Answer (score -3):

Unrelated to your build.gradle file,

Sharing hoping it might help someone else -

I was having similar issue it was because one of the line in build.gradle -

```
android {
    ...
    publishNonDefault true // remove this line and it should work!
}
```

[Here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) you can get more detail about publishNonDefualt -

---

It is also possible to publish all variants of a library. We are planning to allow this while using a normal project-to-project dependency (like shown above), but this is not possible right now due to limitations in Gradle (we are working toward fixing those as well).
Publishing of all variants are not enabled by default. The snippet below enables this feature:

---

Comment: I didn't have that line in my build.gradle when I was fasing the issue.

Comment: I don't have that line in my build.gradle.  What is the relevance?