# Unable to create Build Variant after Giraffe update in android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, build, build.gradle

After creating new project I am trying to create multiple build variant like dev, production, etc... but unable to create new variant

[image]

I am trying to create multiple variant build. gradle does not allow to create new build variant

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63786331) solution