# ReactNative Android: release error metro not run

Tags: android, react-native

I generated the key and added the following settings

```
android {
...
signingConfigs {
    release {
        if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
```

Then I generate the output

```
cd android && ./gradlew bundleRelease
```

But when I upload the application to the Google Play Market and install it on the phone, it starts and immediately closes. And in the logs it says that Metro is not running.

I also tried running the app with the command

```
npx react-native run-android --variant=release
```

But the error is the same. Has anyone experienced this? There is no such error on iPhone

Comment: Having same problem with my app as well. Any solution so far?

Comment: this option helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42650731/unable-to-switch-to-debug-build-variant-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
$ cd your-app-folder
$ cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Comment: Google does not allow apk upload

Answer (score 0):

If you are targetting Android 13 then I think your `index.android.bundle` file might not be created correctly. To fix this, run the following command,

`npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle`

This will create the correct `index.android.bundle` file and you will be able to run the app.