# Android Gradle 2.2 Not Allowing ShrinkResources for Signed APK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

As part of the Android Studio 2.2 roll out I updated my Gradle Build tools to v2.2.  After doing that my signed APK build process fails because I have shrinkResources = true.

Once I switch back to Gradle v2.1.3 OR set shrinkResources = false everything works fine.  Here's my app gradle build file:

```
    android {
    signingConfigs {

    }
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 4
        versionName "0.0.4"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            proguardFile 'C:/Users/code/testapp/app/proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

With Gradle set to v2.2 here's the build error I get when generating a signed APK

[image]

Does anyone know why this is occurring and if there's a work around?  I've Googled around a bit and have seen some older Android Bug reports about alpha and beta Gradle builds having this issue, but the reports I found were >6 months old (and for previous Gradle versions).

P.S. I know that minifyEnabled = false currently, i have yet to investigate the correct set of proguard rules for my included libraries to prevent the Signed Build from erroring out due to missing libs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use `shrinkResources` you have to use `minifyEnabled`

As per [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html):

> Resource shrinking works only in conjunction with code shrinking.
>   After the code shrinker removes all unused code, the resource shrinker
>   can identify which resources the app still uses. This is especially
>   true when you add code libraries that include resources—you must
>   remove unused library code so the library resources become
>   unreferenced and, thus, removable by the resource shrinker.
>
> To enable resource shrinking, set the shrinkResources property to true
>   in your build.gradle file (alongside minifyEnabled for code
>   shrinking).

Comment: Thanks! Must have been a "feature" that it worked previously

Answer (score 4):

use

```
minifyEnabled false
shrinkResources false
```

or

```
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
```

may be a bug on android gradle plugin

wait google fix bugs