# Google Places not working for release apk

Tags: android, google-places-api

Google Places for android not working for release apk, only works for debug apk even though I added both SHA1 certificate fingerprint for both debug key and for release key. I don't know what is wrong this is how I got release key sha1 fingerprint `keytool -list -v -keystore releasekey.jks -alias aliasForKey` and entered correct password then got correct output with no errors `Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:
         SHA1: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:
         SHA256: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Places for Android API key does not work on app from Play Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51159372/google-places-for-android-api-key-does-not-work-on-app-from-play-store)

Comment: The thing to realize here is that when you publish your app to the Play Store, Google removes your signature and then resigns it.  The SHA1 hash you need to use has to come from the Play Store console, _not_ from your local call to `keytool`.

Comment: Actually, I don't know why but you have to use the SHA256 Key available in the playstore developer console. With this one, your Google API will work.

Comment: @Maxouille can I use the SHA256 key I got from `Keytool`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I did not yet upload app to play store, I just singed it using release key but it still don't work

Comment: @Maxouille I tried using SHA256 but Google places console wont allow me to add it because it is invalid key, I get this error `Invalid SHA-1 certificate fingerprint`

Comment: It's such a mess these key for google api ... In Android Studio, you have to use a SHA256 key, not a SHA1 as far as I remember.

Answer (score 1):

If minifyEnabled is true, then paste these line in your proguard-rules.pro file

```
-keepnames class * implements java.io.Serializable

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
     static final long serialVersionUID;
     private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
     !static !transient <fields>;
     !private <fields>;
     !private <methods>;
     private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
     private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
     java.lang.Object writeReplace();
     java.lang.Object readResolve();
 }
```