# Release INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES

Tags: java, android, release

If I launch my app from android studio on the terminal with build variant debug, the app is installed correctly. If instead imposed as build variant release, I get the following error:
09/06 16:27:07: Launching 'app' on samsung SM-G973F.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES
APK signature verification failed.
Retry

Comment: here the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802401/how-to-debug-the-android-app-in-release-mode-using-android-studio

Comment: have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Thanks for linking to the answer! It worked

Answer (score 0):

That error is show because you should sign your Release build apk. You can read this article about it
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Comment: I have already signed my app, I have also uploaded it to the play store and it works correctly. The problem is that in android studio I can't launch the release version on the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, simply delete the **debug.keystore** file stored in one of the following locations:

> ~/.android/ on OS X and Linux
>   C:\Documents and Settings\user.android\ on Windows XP
>   C:\Users\user.android\ on Windows Vista and Windows 7, 8, and 10

The next time you build and run a debug version of your app, Android Studio regenerates a new keystore and debug key.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but the answer may help others

in my case, the problem was in app build.gradle

the compileSdkVersion,minSdkVersion,targetSdkVersion were equal to "R" so I changed it to

```
compileSdkVersion 29

minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 29
```

make sure that the minsdkversion should be less than your phone apiversion

and then I could install and run the project on my phone from android studio